# PDF presentation software with preview of next slide and annotations

Tags: windows, pdf, presentation

I am looking for a PDF reader / presentation software **for Windows** that would allow me to show on one monitor the PDF presentation, while the other monitor would show a combination of the current slide, the next slide, notes, and time elapsed. Essentially something like [pdfpc](https://davvil.github.io/pdfpc/), but for Windows. The only thing that I've found is [open-pdf-presenter](https://code.google.com/p/open-pdf-presenter/), but its memory usage is extremely high, and so even a 400KB PDF file makes my computer crash (you would think that 4GB would be enough... The developer insists that it's a feature).

Does anyone know of any such software that would work for me? Thanks.

Comment: "`The developer insists that it's a feature`" - the "`developer`" ought to be ashamed of themselves! Ask the "`developer`" if they will open source the app

Answer (score 3):

The [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) [Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) program allows you to do at least most of this, (I don't have any pdf files with embedded notes to test on at the moment).

- Open a pdf in impress,
- Press F5 and the first page is displayed full screen on the other monitor or the projector
- Local screen shows current page and next page, *you can toggle on notes as well*.
- You can add notes, transitions, timings, etc., but probably then need to save as an impress presentation afterwards.
- Free
- Cross Platform *I just tried it on Windows 10 but I know it works on OS-X, Linux, Windows 7/8, etc.*

### Note

When opening .pdf documents in Impress you need to scroll down the file types to the Impress block of file types and select .pdf from there:
[image]
Result of opening your sample file in Impress as above:
[image: Edit Screen]

### Result of Pressing F5 (On Dual Screen PC):

[image]

### Toggle On Notes

[image]

### Versions Used for the above:

MS Windows 10, LibreOffice 4.4.2.2

Comment: Impress doesn't seem to be able to open PDF files. Instead they are opened in Draw, and they are completely garbled (overlapping text, spaces inserted at random, math formulas are a mess), in addition to taking an inordinate amount of time to open (5+ minutes on my decent computer). Not an option.

Comment: @user17860 - I just opened one to try it you need to scroll down the file types until you get to the Impress file types and then select pdf from that group,

Comment: It does open in Impress now, but the text is still messed up and math formulas all go berserk ([this](https://i.imgur.com/f7JJ1z1.png) is supposed tor read "a . b = b . a" -- certainly not a clock...).

Comment: Do you have a sample file that you could share?

Comment: Sure: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07365659759616859271 (I hope this file host is OK). Created using pdflatex & beamer.

Comment: Added some screenshots to the answer.

Comment: Very weird, here is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/2s7LYDy.png I guess I'm missing some fonts...

Comment: It looks like the dot product is being replaced with a clock on your system.

Comment: Perhaps a font needs to be installed? Or at least embedded in the pdf?